# How find that button and press, selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

May I ask, please, how to find that element and press? (see picture)
And if you don't mind, can you please say me, how to press the above elements. This is from Google Colab.

[Image of that site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcKg7.jpg)

I tried:

```
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div > div.cell-execution-indicator > iron-icon"))).click()
```

And

```
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cell-f69fxCq40YId"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/colab-run-button//div'))).click()
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: This is from Google Colab, this is my "note", so there is no way to send it. But...If I give all people the right to open my note with a link? Can I send you that?

Comment: It's the same site for everyone. I see that on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `css`: `.cell-execution-container` or by class name `cell-execution-container` or `xpath` `//div[@class='cell-execution-container']`

Comment: Doesn't work||||wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(name(),'iron-icon')]"))).click()

Comment: I see. i changed my answer. `iron-icon` is not unique selector. The locator above is unique. The arrow element you are looking for, I guess.

Comment: Now it should be correct :)  (see the updated answer)

Comment: He found and press it, but...The code doesn't run.

Comment: Wow, thank you VERY much! I need to learn the XPATH, for not to bother you with this kind of questions, sorry, have a good day ^^

Comment: It's OKay. In the previous time I learned this point to answer you, so it's really good for me too :)

Comment: Can I add, please, that this work only if "block" of code is 1 or 2 string. But when I try it with >3 strings of code, this is doesn't work. May I...ask for your help again, please.

Comment: Sure. But somewhat later, an hour later. Write me to messenger https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011831197069 real mensch

Comment: Wow, I found the solutions myself, cool. I added ActionChains and write  |||      ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()